# Show more link not detecting character limit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I was trying to add the show more link at the end of my paragraph but the more link is not appearing correctly or not truncating at the right character count.

Code here: https://jsfiddle.net/7sp0mpp8/

```
$(document).ready(function() {


    var showChar = 300;
    var ellipsestext = "";
    var moretext = "more";
    var lesstext = "less";
    $('.more').each(function() {
        var content = $(this).html();

        if(content.length > showChar) {

            var c = content.substr(0, showChar);
            var h = content.substr(showChar-1, content.length - showChar);

            var html = c + '<span class="moreelipses">'
                             + ellipsestext 
                         + '</span>' 
                         + '<span class="morecontent">' 
                             + '<span>' 
                                 + h 
                             + '</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;' 
                             + '<a href="" class="morelink">' 
                                 + moretext 
                             + '</a>' 
                         + '</span>';

            $(this).html(html);
        }

    });

    $(".morelink").click(function(){
        if($(this).hasClass("less")) {
            $(this).removeClass("less");
            $(this).html(moretext);
        } else {
            $(this).addClass("less");
            $(this).html(lesstext);
        }

        $(this).parent().prev().toggle();
        $(this).prev().toggle();

        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Your code works, you just didn't include jQuery in your fiddle. Also note that you need to swap the text labels around: https://jsfiddle.net/7sp0mpp8/

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan your fiddle link is the same link as OP's. Did you make the edits in a fiddle as in your comment?

Comment: Whoops, my mistake: https://jsfiddle.net/7sp0mpp8/1/ Thanks @Nukeface

Answer (score 1):

You had 3 main problems here:

1. Forget to include jQuery library
2. Getting substring into h variable was bad - it was taking last character from c variable as well
3. Finally you missed to add display: none (or something similar) to your `<span>` with hidden additional content.

Fixed version

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var showChar = 30;
    var ellipsestext = "";
    var moretext = "more";
    var lesstext = "less";
    $('.more').each(function() {
        var content = $(this).html();

        if(content.length > showChar) {
            var c = content.substr(0, showChar);
            var h = content.substr(showChar, content.length - showChar);

            var html = c + '<span class="moreelipses">'+ellipsestext+'</span><span class="morecontent"><span style="display:none;">' + h + '</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="" class="morelink">'+moretext+'</a></span>';
            $(this).html(html);
        }

    });

    $(".morelink").click(function(){
        if($(this).hasClass("less")) {
            $(this).removeClass("less");
            $(this).html(moretext);
        } else {
            $(this).addClass("less");
            $(this).html(lesstext);
        }
        $(this).parent().prev().toggle();
        $(this).prev().toggle();
        return false;
    });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/7sp0mpp8/2/

Comment: You are awesome, But can i have that extented text with animation like slide or show or toggle, this is wht i am too looking for. thank u in advance

Comment: i was tried but that extended text coming with animation but it was coming from new line

Comment: Its impossible by simple way. jquery slideUp/Down() and similar methods works correctly only with block html elements, but that text node is inline.

Comment: only what you can do is to appending letters to DOM letter by letter in loop

Comment: yeah, i was tried all the methods, but dint worked for me, any way thank u

Comment: Because its impossible (even trough CSS implementation) :)

Answer (score 0):

**Add Jquery** and then you need a little fix that is to hide the css for morecontent intially. Add `$(".morecontent").css('display', 'none');` and also add the `morecontent` class to the inner rathe than the outer span like

```
var html = c + '<span class="moreelipses">'+ellipsestext+'</span><span ><span class="morecontent">' + h + '</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="" class="morelink">'+moretext+'</a></span>';
```

Complete snippet.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var showChar = 300;
    var ellipsestext = "";
    var moretext = "more";
    var lesstext = "less";
    $('.more').each(function() {
        var content = $(this).text();
    console.log(content.length)
        if(content.length > showChar) {

            var c = content.substr(0, showChar);
            var h = content.substr(showChar-1, content.length - showChar);
      console.log(c);
            var html = c + '<span class="moreelipses">'+ellipsestext+'</span><span ><span class="morecontent">' + h + '</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="" class="morelink">'+moretext+'</a></span>';

            $(this).html(html);
      $(".morecontent").css('display', 'none');
        }

    });

    $(".morelink").click(function(){
        if($(this).hasClass("less")) {
            $(this).removeClass("less");
            $(this).html(moretext);
        } else {
            $(this).addClass("less");
            $(this).html(lesstext);
        }
        $(this).parent().prev().toggle();
        $(this).prev().toggle();
        return false;
    });
});
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/7sp0mpp8/3/)